# Null when I try to create an array on localStorage js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a test array in localStorage but when I make it the result is null in every index.

My js file:

```
var hola, probando;
var prueba = new Array (hola, probando);
localStorage.setItem("prueba", JSON.stringify(prueba));
```

As a result, localStorage store this:

```
prueba: "[null, null]"
```

Somebody can help me? :(

Thank you,

Comment: Your variables `hola` and `probando` have no value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var hola = "try";
var probando = "this";
var prueba = new Array (hola, probando);
localStorage.setItem("prueba", JSON.stringify(prueba));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var hola = "first";
var probando = "second";
var prueba = new Array (hola, probando);
localStorage.setItem("prueba", JSON.stringify(prueba));
```

for first elem

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("prueba"))[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables "hola" and "probando" are empty
Tested your code in my javascript console and it worked

Read them out then with

```
localStorage.getItem("prueba");
```